# concatenate variable with background style broken in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#home").append('<div style="background:url("http://example.com/images/'+obj[i]+'.jpg")"');
```

what's wrong here? I think I'd closed it properly..

Comment: What is obj[i] meant to be?

Comment: @RichardMacarthy some value for example, abc

Comment: no one know this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issues with mis-matching quotes - you need to escape the double quotes in the `url` properties' value, or remove them. You have also not closed the `div` tag properly. Try this:

```
$("#home").append('<div style="background:url(http://example.com/images/' + obj[i] + '.jpg)"></div>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrn1hdma/)

Comment: I got this worked! thanks Rory, but I don't know why sometime it doesn't need `` in the url();

Comment: Glad it worked :) The `"` are only required when there is a space in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

the problem issued with the string you're building:

```
'<div style="background:url("http://example.com/images/'+obj[i]+'.jpg")"'
```

let's assume obj[i]==1.

your div will look like this:

```
<div style="background:url("http://example.com/images/1.jpg")"
```

notice two important isssues:

1. the div has no closing ('>' character)
2. the style attribute is "background:url(" - having same type of quotes prevent the navigator to understand you.

try use:

```
 $("#home").append('<div style="background:url(/'http://example.com/images/'+obj[i]+'.jpg/')">');
```

good luck!